# How to export MIDI with foot controller in Acid Pro 7

Tags: midi, daw

I have a e-durm track recorded in MIDI in Acid Pro 7.
I want that track in another project.
I tried File->Export Midi but it is missing the "foot controller (hi hat)" envelope.
How do I include that envelope in export?

Another thing is, where are the recorded midi files stored? It says "Midi Recording 12" on the drum track. If I can find that on disk, I can just take it from there.

Thanks